# Unix: Location to save install executable files

Tags: unix

Is there any place that people used to save installer/ executable files/ gz files which download from source website? Could we discuss 2 cases: login as root or as regular user?

Comment: you should never log in as root unless you really need to :) you can get superuser access with the sudo command

Comment: Thanks for all replies. To be more specific, the OS is CentOS. I am actually looking for place to save pre-build / built gz files. Just like saving regular scripts in /usr/local/bin and regular logs in /var/local/logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put them in `/usr/local/src`, though it is rare to find anything distributed in *only* that way any more.

Reasoning:

- There are a local rather than system adddition, so somewhere under `/usr/local` or `/opt` according to your preference or you OS's convention.
- In generally you wouldn't want the installers on the usual `$PATH` so not `bin`.
- They are related to building/installing stuff,

If doing it in a user space, I'd user `$HOME/src` for similar reasons.

Answer (score 2):

really depends on your preferences, so it's hard to answer without more info.
for my part, however, i'll explain what I do at home and save you the rant about what I'm stuck with at work ..

at Home on Archlinux :

i build packages for my desktop or for my virtual servers. On all these machines, I have certain NFS mounts that I load in and then bind mount to my $HOME for convenience. Because of this, the $HOME/build folder needs $host abstraction so that i know for which host I built the package. ( i build packages in "naked" build virtual machines so as to better catch dependencies )

```
$HOME/build
$HOME/build/$host/$app
$HOME/build/$host/$app/$srcpkg
$HOME/build/$host/$app/$buildroot
```

once packages are built, the compiled package goes into $HOME/package which is another bind mount that my filesharing virtual server offers via ftp to tie into my package manager.

i've no no idea what your level of expertise is, so please forgive me if i take moment to mention that you should always try to build packages as a non-root user, create a package, and sudo install via your package manager. it'll save you alot of hassle in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

I have a /files directory created which has several directories inside it such as movies, pictures, downloads, source.

This is what I use as both root and user. /files is owned by the user root and group 'userfiles'. Every user that needs access to it is made a member of 'userfiles'

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "Unix" (the trademarked OS) or some Unix-like system, e.g. Linux or one of the BSDs?

Generally, you shouldn't put them all in one place.  Executables go somewhere in your path, data files probably somewhere else.  You need to be much more specific if you want useful answers.

Comment: i think he means executable installers, for example Nvidia's binary driver installer (downloaded as a `.sh`, which extracts the files to install from itself when run).  you wouldn't want *that* on your path.